# How to change downloading name in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask's `send_file` to serve a file at a specific URL. However, the name of the saved file is always the last part of the URL, like `download`, instead of the real name `table.csv`. How can I return the file with the correct filename?

```py
@app.route("/download")
def download()
    return send_file("/path/to/table.csv")
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to set a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=....` HTTP header for the browser to use the correct filename.

You can have `send_file()` set this header for you by setting the `as_attachment=True` argument. The filename is then taken from the file object you passed in. Use the `download_name` argument to explicitly set a different filename:

```
return send_file(os.path.join(filepath, filename), as_attachment=True)
```

From the [`flask.send_file` documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.send_file):

> - **`as_attachment`** – Indicate to a browser that it should offer to save the file instead of displaying it.
> - **`download_name`** – The default name browsers will use when saving the file. Defaults to the passed file name.

<sub>Prior to Flask 2.0, `download_name` was called `attachment_filename`.</sub>

You may want to use the [`flask.send_from_directory()` function](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.send_from_directory) instead. That function first ensures that the filename exists (raising a `NotFound` if not), and ensures that the filename doesn't contain any `..` relative elements that might be used to 'escape' the directory. Use this for all filenames taken from untrusted sources:

```
return send_from_directory(filepath, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: It works, but I had issues with http browser cache which didn't retry to download and got same filename. So folks who found this solution not working, just to make sure try using incognito/private mode browser to verify

Answer (score 16):

When using [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), setting the `as_attachment` and `download_name` may not work by default. You need to allow the `Content-Disposition` header with [`expose_headers`](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_cors.CORS), otherwise it will not be sent to the client.

```py
from flask import Flask, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, expose_headers=["Content-Disposition"])
```

```py
return send_file(
    "/path/to/file.txt",
    as_attachment=True,
    download_name="custom_name.txt"
)
```

If you want to use JavaScript to download and save the file, one option is to use [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) to download the file, and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save it. FileSaver will use the `Content-Disposition` header set by `send_file` as the filename by default.

```js
let response = await axios.get(downloadUrl, downloadConfig);
FileSaver.saveAs(response.data);
```

Comment: You can simply expose the Content-Disposition header

`cors = CORS(app, expose_headers=["Content-Disposition"])`

Answer (score 7):

In some cases the filename is still not visible. To have it for sure you should set "x-filename" header and to expose this header.

```
from flask import send_file
response = send_file(absolute_image_path, mimetype='image/jpeg', attachment_filename=name, as_attachment=True)
response.headers["x-filename"] = name
response.headers["Access-Control-Expose-Headers"] = 'x-filename'
return response
```

**Update**: Prior to Flask 2.0, *download_name* was called *attachment_filename*.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the browser didn't download the file until I passed the `mimetype` parameter.

```
@app.route('/download_report')
def download_report():
    return send_file('Report.csv', mimetype='application/x-csv', download_name='summary_report.csv', as_attachment=True)
```