# Change the downloading file name in Flask

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I have created a api which returns a tar file. When i try to download it in swagger it gets downloaded with some random garbage name like `"application_octet-stream_generate_blob_https___editor.swagger.io_9ecd1754-0f85-4ed7-97ca-816bb446e5e2"` the file name should be migration.tar

This is my code

```
response = send_file(fpath, as_attachment=True, mimetype="application/octet-stream",download_name="migration.tar")

return response
```

When i try to download it in postman it works fine
Thanks in advance..

Comment: whats is the expected file name?

Comment: migration.tar@sarathravi

Comment: add the line ` as_attachment=True` in your send_file and check

Comment: its already added

Comment: please go through the answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543951/how-to-change-downloading-name-in-flask

Comment: tried it all.didnt work..:(

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name of the file using the parameter `download_name`.

```
return send_file(
    fpath, 
    mimetype="application/octet-stream", 
    as_attachment=True, 
    download_name="migration.tar"
)
```